# Can "trends" be queried with the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api, questions, tags

I've studied the Stack Exchange API to some extent (although I'm a newbie to such things), and it appears I can query the database using many criteria. But does Stack Exchange store any "trends"? For example, among the set of tags [A, B, C, and D], which one had the most questions and/or the greatest increase since last week? I'm guessing I have to keep my own local database and draw my own conclusions by running a set of queries on a regular basis. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

For trends like this, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is a better option (if you know SQL; if you don't, check out the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)). About the only downside is that it is refreshed once per week, on Sunday morning; the API gives you real-time results.

The API *would* be able to provide the number of questions asked  in the last week for certain tags, e.g. [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2021-07-20&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=support&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true) gives you all [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions on Stack Apps since July 20th (your question is the only one):

[image]